# I writed a middleware (download), after running directly into the pipeline, did not enter the spider, which is why?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I've already set downloadmiddleware in the setting.py file

```
class JsScrollMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def process_request(cls, request, spider):
        if spider.job_cfg.scroll:
            scroll_to_the_end_get_data(spider)
            html=spider.driver.page_source
            spider.job_cfg.scroll=False
            return HtmlResponse(url=spider.driver.current_url, encoding='utf-8', body=html, request=request)
```

Comment: `process_request` method of downloader middleware should be instance method, not a class method.